# Custom Validator in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to implement a custom validator for @RequestHeader and move the if-else  statement from controller?

```
@PostMapping(path_to_endpoint)
public Map<String, Object> changePassword(@Parameter(hidden = true) @RequestHeader String userId,
                                            @RequestHeader String old_password,
                                            @RequestHeader String new_password,
                                            @RequestHeader String confirm_password,
                                            HttpServletResponse http_response) {

    final Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    if (new_password.equals(confirm_password)) {
//do some login here
    } else {
      httpResponse.setStatus(SC_BAD_REQUEST);
      response.put(STATUS, 400);
      response.put(MESSAGE, "Passwords do not match!!");
    }
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: Note that it is very odd to send these as request headers; more usual is either form parameters, which can be collected into `@ModelAttribute`, or a JSON `@RequestBody`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Found that in the codebase. For now, I am trying to refactor it.